# Usar lambda com Ado.Net

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda, ado.net

Usando sqldatareader e ado.net, dá para usar lambda com linq ou só lambda ou só linq? Essa não é uma pergunta múltipla, mas linq e lambda sempre estão juntos, por isso os vários "?", ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho muito pouca experiência com sqldatareader mas contextualizando...

O **ADO.NET** é um conjunto de classes que expõem serviços de acesso a dados para desenvolvedores do .NET Framework. Os resultados da manipulação de dados são processados, colocados em um objeto **DataSet** do ADO.NET para serem expostos para o usuário.

O **LINQ** (Language-Integrated Query) permite que os desenvolvedores formem consultas baseadas em conjuntos no código de seus aplicativos, sem precisar usar uma linguagem de consulta separada, como por exemplo usar SQL no código C#. Porém o **LINQ trabalha com fontes de dados do tipo IEnumerable**.

Você consegue usar todas essas opções, tanto linq quanto lambda com ado.net:

Uma opção, que acredito ser interessante para você, seria implementar um método de extensão que retornaria um IEnumerable para iterar sobre as rows do seu reader.
Nesse post tem um exemplo: http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/Consuming_a_DataReader_with_LINQ.aspx

Outra opção é você usar o LINQ to DataSet, que converte os dados de suas coleções de objetos em coleções baseadas em IEnumerable.

Sobre o uso de lambda achei esse exemplo também, mas não sei se é exatamente o que você deseja:
http://mvcbricks.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/c-30-lambda-expressions-in-charge-of.html

Answer (score 1):

## Usando sqldatareader e ado.net, dá para usar lambda com linq ou só lambda ou só linq?

Sim

O que você chama de "lambda" é na verdade um parâmetro do tipo `Func<TSource, T>`, que é um **predicado**. Ele não coexiste com o [linq](/questions/tagged/linq), como você pode ver por este link:

> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Da mesma forma que o [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) não necessariamente precise usar predicados para funcionar, conforme exemplos do link abaixo:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx